# How return this data in json for each?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

i have json values like this, i try to use for each to get the result one bye one, but it was not returning to me

```
"[{"id":6,"userid":13,"title":"business3","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},

{"id":7,"userid":13,"title":"business6 arabic","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},

{"id":10,"userid":13,"title":"E-commerce","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},

{"id":11,"userid":8,"title":"Auto phone parts","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},

{"id":19,"userid":8,"title":"التجارة الإلكترونية","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},

{"id":20,"userid":8,"title":"E-commerce -online shopping","bussinessTypeid":8,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},

{"id":21,"userid":13,"title":"My new Business","bussinessTypeid":6,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]}]"
```

can anyone guide me to achive this

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's being treated as a string try to remove the ( " ) on the start and end of it something like:

```
var json = [{"id":6,"userid":13,"title":"business3","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},{"id":7,"userid":13,"title":"business6 arabic","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},{"id":10,"userid":13,"title":"E-commerce","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},{"id":11,"userid":8,"title":"Auto phone parts","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":"","cntry":[{"id":"1","name":"Afghanistan"}]},{"id":19,"userid":8,"title":"التجارة الإلكترونية","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},{"id":20,"userid":8,"title":"E-commerce -online shopping","bussinessTypeid":8,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]},{"id":21,"userid":13,"title":"My new Business","bussinessTypeid":6,"photurl":".jpg","cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}]}];
```

Then do the iteration:

```
for(id in json){
 alert(json[id]['id']);
}
```

and don't include any next line spaces are ok as long as they are separated by a comma (,)

Comment: how can i remmove the starting(") & ending(")  ?

Comment: show us the code that generates this result so we may know

Comment: using that i can able to retrive this data only /*{"id":6,"userid":13,"title":"business3","bussinessTypeid":1,"photurl":" */" i am trying to get this values too cntry":[{"id":"9","name":"Bahrain"}

Comment: how do you get this data? through ajax? if that is the case firstly you need to parse it in javascript for it to be converted to an object type as mentioned on the first answer you may use parseJson() or use eval function of javascript example: var json = eval('('+data+')');
the data is variable string where the json string is passed then you will have the variable json as an object and iterate over it.

Answer (score 0):

Use [parseJson()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/)

> Description: Takes a well-formed JSON string and returns the resulting
>   JavaScript object.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each(data, function(key, value){
 console.log(value.id, value.title);
  $.each(value.cntry, function(key2, value2){
    console.log(value2.id, value2.name);
  })
});
```

Try this with jquery

```
var data = jQuery.parseJSON(yourJsonInString); //or this parser below
var data = JSON.parse(yourJsonInString);
```